# ASP.NET MVC passing an ID to ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a clickable link that must invoke my sql statement , however my field is an integer and ActionLink will stops and gives me an error that my item.Emp_ID is not a string.

In MVC4 C# is there any other ways that I can create a link to invoke my sql statement??

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.EMP_ID, "OfficerReport", new { id = item.EMP_ID })
```

Thank you.

Comment: integer it is my employee id

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment as the answer below made it redundant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.EMP_ID.ToString(), "OfficerReport", new { id = item.EMP_ID })
```

**parameter 1)** Link Text

**parameter 2)** Action Name

**parameter 3)** route values

Answer (score 1):

Add ToString at the end if EMP_ID as shown below

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.EMP_ID.ToString(), "OfficerReport", new { id = item.EMP_ID });
```

More Information :-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", // <-- Link text

                 "About", // <-- Action Method Name   

                 "Home", // <-- Controller Name   

                 null, // <-- Route value   

                 null // <-- htmlArguments      
                 )
```